# jQuery - Allow only numeric and limit characters - does not work when text is highlighted

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have the following jQuery to allow only numbers and limit the length.  It works fine, but when the text is highlighted, i cannot edit the text, it does nothing.  Is there a way to enter a new value when the text is highlighted with the same condition

```
$('body').on('keydown', 'input[type=number][maxlength]', function (event) {
    var key = event.keyCode || event.charCode;
    var charcodestring = String.fromCharCode(event.which);
    var txtVal = $(this).val();
    var maxlength = $(this).attr('maxlength');
    var regex = new RegExp('^[0-9]+$');
    // 8 = backspace 46 = Del 13 = Enter 39 = Left 37 = right Tab = 9
    if (key == 8 || key == 46 || key == 13 || key == 37 || key == 39 || key == 9) {
        return true;
    }
    // maxlength allready reached
    if (txtVal.length == maxlength) {
        return false;
    }
    // pressed key have to be a number
    if (!regex.test(charcodestring)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
});
```

Thanks

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. When I highlight the text, I can type something and it replaces the highlighted text. If I press Delete, it deletes the highlighted text.

Comment: @Barmar Delete and backspace works fine, but not highlight.  I'm using MVC and this is how i call this function. `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Cust.Zip_Code, new { autocomplete = "off", placeholder = "Zip", @type = "number", maxlength = "5" })`

Comment: How are you trying to highlight? If you're trying to use the keyboard, like Ctl-a, that won't work because it doesn't match any of the `if (key == ...)` tests.

Comment: @Barmar using mouse key down or mouse double click, not Ctl-A

Comment: I suspect the MVC framework you're using has its own event handler, and your code is conflicting with it.

Comment: If you tag the question with the framework name, maybe someone who knows it will be able to help you. I don't use any MVC so I can't help.